# Location services error after upgrading to iOS8

Tags: objective-c, ios8, core-location

I'm trying to support iOS7 & 8 location services. When I run on my iOS8 device, I get this error:

```
"MyApp depending on legacy on-demand authorization, which is not supported for new apps"
```

I have a when in use entry in my plist. Here's my code:

```
    if ([_locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [_locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    } else {
        [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
  if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {
    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
  }
}
```

Why does this error show up?

Comment: where does this error showed up?

Comment: This error shows up in iOS simulator > Debug > System Log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was implementing a deprecated callback from the location services and not implementing the new one. There was no compiler warning but developers reading this should check the documentation for location services delegates in their code.

DEPRECATED it's the first method in the documentation for the delegate. This whole question was a case of RTFM.

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
  didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
         fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_6, __MAC_NA, __IPHONE_2_0, __IPHONE_6_0);

Comment: Could you please tell what was the deprecated callback you were using ?

Comment: Wow, why was this flagged down? I gave a correct answer to my own question. I'm not at the code right now but it was related to verifying the user's permissions.

Comment: You could be more specific in your answer. It seems like after you problem was solved, you didn't care about others who could be having the same issue. Sharing the specifics of your answer could have been seen as simply generous.

Comment: Fair enough. I don't remember which callback it was though. I opened the in-IDE documentation and saw "deprecated" for the callback I had.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get this error in swift is that you did not ask user explicit permission to use location services which was fine until iOS 8.
Starting from iOS 8 you should explicitly ask permission to use location services.

iOS version  >= 8

```
self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
self.locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
```

iOS version < 8

```
self.locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these two key in info.plist with value string "Location is required to find out where you are".

NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription